# Preprocessing with browserify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, bundling-and-minification

How can I preprocess a function call with browserify?

In a large js file, at one point, I need to pass a JSON object to a variable but this JSON object may only be created by a function call:

```
var myvar = Ractive.parse('mytemplate.html');
```

If I write this function call like so, this line of code is appeared in the `bundle.js` file as is. I simply want something like:

```
var myvar = THIS_WILL_RUN_WHILE_BROWSERIFYING(Ractive.parse('mytemplate.html'));
```

so in `bundle.js` I expect to see something like:

```
var myvar = [{myobj:4},{x:1,y:2}];
```

How can I make this happen with browserify (with Gulp)?

Comment: `var myvar = [myobj:{x:1,y:2}];`  You mean you want it to create invalid javascript. :)

Comment: I don't use browserfy, but looking at the doc -> https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#transforms  You might want to create your own transform,.. There is an example of replacing `$CWD` with `process.cwd()` looks like something you could try.

Comment: Not too sure what it is you want to do and it's been a long time since I've used Ractive, but have you looked at https://github.com/marcello3d/node-ractify ?

Comment: @Keith thank you for the lead, I made [a minimal transform](https://github.com/aktos-io/aktos-scada2/blob/master/src/lib/aea/ractive-preparserify.ls) that takes a Jade (Pug) file and replace the parsed output with `RACTIVE_PREPARSE('path/to/my-template.jade')` line. Thank you :) (you may consider move your comment to a new answer, btw)

Comment: @cartant I didn't get how to use node-ractify. Moreover, I have to feed the template input with `.jade` files, which `node-ractify` does not seem to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browserify allows you to create custom transforms, there is a good example of how to create transforms at the following link.

https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#transforms

The example of doing a replace of the `$CWD` with `process.cwd()`, appeared to be a good starting point for the OP to create the transform required.

In case of potential future dead links, here is the example.

```
var through = require('through2');

module.exports = function (file) {
    return through(function (buf, enc, next) {
        this.push(buf.toString('utf8').replace(/\$CWD/g, process.cwd()));
        next();
    });
};
```